# Showing multiple of the same <divs> on the same line

Tags: php, css, html

I am retrieving a list of products from a database and want to display them all in a rows of 3 columns not using a table though. So I want 3 divs to be displayed side by side. then below.

```
<div class="productindividualdisplay">
    <div class="productphoto">
        <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-_xP-UUa4D0c/UfAo1eYxURI/AAAAAAAAAT4/xsibNtxZceQ/s320/Books.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="250" height="250"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="producttitle">
        <a href="productdisplay.php?name=<?echo $row['productid']?>"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="productprice">
        <?php echo "<div id='productrrp'> &euro;" . $row['rrp'] . "</div>";
        if(is_null($offeringprice)) {
        echo "Not Available";
        } else {
                    echo "&euro;" .  $offeringprice['price']; 
                    }

                        ?>
        </div>
```

That is my code but it is just displaying the divs below each other. Is it possible so it fills up the row before starting another one?

Comment: Can you provide your css or a jsfiddle?

Comment: yes, it is. You use some CSS to give them a width, make them inline-blocks, and ensure that their container will fit three, but not four.

Comment: Alternatively float left and add a br after each 3. Or investigate [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com)

Comment: Use CSS: `display: table` and `display: table-row`. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/6G8Qz/)**</kbd>

```
<div class="product-wrapper">

  <div class="productindividualdisplay">
    <div class="productphoto">
      <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-_xP-UUa4D0c/UfAo1eYxURI/AAAAAAAAAT4/xsibNtxZceQ/s320/Books.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="250" height="250">
    </div>
    <div class="producttitle">
      <a href="productdisplay.php?name=<?echo $row['productid']?>">Product Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="productprice">
      <span>$100</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  ...more products...

</div>


.product-wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.productindividualdisplay {
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 260px;
  margin: 5px 5px 15px 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -3px #333;
}
.productphoto {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
.producttitle a {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.productprice {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `display: inline-block;` on the divs's css.

Answer (score 1):

A `<div>` is a [block-level element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block-level_element#Block_elements). Block-level elements, like `<h1>`, `<p>`, `<table>` etc. will (by default) span the entire width of their parent elements, so they can't be positioned next to eachother.

You can change this behavior, however, using the following CSS rule:

```
div.column {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will render the `<div>`s as inline blocks.

Now you can give it a certain `width` so that three divs fit into a row. Do note that, when you leave whitespace between two `<div>` elements, there will be some visual whitespace. If you give all `div`'s a width of 33.333333333%, the extra whitespace will cause their combined width to exceed 100%, so the third `div` will move to the next line.

You can simply prevent this by making sure there is no whitespace between the HTML elements:

```
<div class="column">
    <p>Some contents here</p>
</div><div class="column">
    <p>As you can see, no whitespace between the two div elements.</p>
</div>
```

Of course you can then use margins to control whitespace manually:

```
div.column {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 3.33333333%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

You might wanna take a look at this article: [Using inline-block to Display a Product Grid View](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-inline-block-to-display-a-product-grid-view) (it uses `<li>`s instead of `<div>`s, but the idea is essentially the same)

Comment: This will only work if the size of the divs is defined, and set in percentage, otherwise the blocks will wrap on the next line.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I suppose that, when more than 3 products are being displayed, the 4th should be on a new line.

Comment: What I mean is that if you set the width to 150px and you have 3 rows, that means that you need 450px otherwise your 3rd block goes on the next line. If you were using percentage this would not happen. But if you were using display: table-row, you are sure that it won't wrap. afaik...

Comment: OK, you are right. I've changed the widths to percentages. However, `table-row` needs extra markup, I don't think that's a good solution.

Comment: Consider using `.column + .column { margin-left: 5%; }`. This will only add two margins to three divs (3 * 30% + 2 * 5% = 100%). Also using `display: table;` on a parent div and `display: table-cell;` on the .columns can kinda do the flex-thing for you.